# Method Cells object -Worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a function, which should be run very often:

```
 Public Function FindNumberofhandle(stsmenthandle As String) As Long
 Dim r As Long
 Dim LastUsedRow As Long
 LastUsedRow = Worksheets(2).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
 For i = 1 To LastUsedRow
     If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = stsmenthandle Then 'ERROR HERE
         r = i
     End If
 Next i
 FindNumberofhandle = r
 End Function
```

I am getting this error:

```
 run time error -2147417748(80010108)
 Method Cells of Object Worksheet failed
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: I have comment it in above code

Comment: Maybe `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)`is not a worksheet but a diagram sheet?

Comment: No, it is a worksheet

Comment: Sorry missed that. What is in stsmenthandle when you get the error? If you do Activeworkbook.name is it the right workbook as 2 lines above you do not use activeworkbook(you could try taking activeworkbook out). what is in i when you error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = stsmenthandle
```

with

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = stsmenthandle
```

Sheets is a collection of Charts Sheets and Worksheets so if a chart sheet is getting picked up when you reference sheets(2) then the property .cells will not work.

Let us know if this works, I am curious as well.

Ignoring cells with error values:

```
If Not iserror(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 2)) then
     If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = stsmenthandle Then
         r = i
     End If
End if
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have another problem now. I recieve this error: `run time error -2147417748(80010108)
 Method Value of Object Range failed`

Comment: Do you have in the range that your code checks cells with Error Values? Maybe that is the issue.. In this case you can add an extra if statement to ignore these. I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: I will test it. The problem is, that the process of data takes a long time then I will get such an error.

Comment: when you find r ie. when the condition Cell Value = stsmenthandle why dont you exit the for loop? this will save time. Just add exit for after r = i.

Comment: Actually it is not possible, because, I would like to finde the last row (Cell), which have the same value with stsmenthandle.

Comment: then change your loop to for i = lastrow to 1 step - 1 and add the exit for statement :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80175/discussion-between-kaja-and-tylerdurden).